# 3d translate does not work in processing

Tags: 3d, processing

oke so i have the following code:

```
import saito.objloader.*; 
OBJModel model; 
import peasy.*;
PeasyCam cam;


void setup() {


   size(1000, 600, OPENGL); 
   model = new OBJModel (this, "goodTest.obj"); 
   cam = new PeasyCam(this, 700); 
   model.scale(250); 
   model.translateToCenter();
```

I want to change model.translateToCenter(); into model.translate(width,0, height/2);

but if i do the above i get the following error: the method translate(PVector) in the type OBJModel is not appicable for the arguments (int,int,int)

and when i just use translate(width,0, height/2); nothing happens

```
   noStroke(); 
   smooth(); 

}

void draw(){
   model.draw();
}
```

could someone help me with this? i dont know how to fix this my self.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of disconnected code? Don't post your whole sketch. Instead, try to post a small example that shows your problem without any of that extra stuff. That just makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you used pushMatrix and popMatrix (read if you haven't hear d of them: https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) and have your translate function inside of the void translateToCenter, you would see no effect on your object as it would only affect any statements within that function between the pushMatrix and popMatrix. Instead, try translating your object within the draw function and using tweak mode (Sketch -> Tweak) to find the translation you desire, and translate your object in the model.draw function, like so:

```
void draw() {  
  pushMatrix();  
  translate(x_variable, y_variable, z_variable);  
  //draw object  
  popMatrix();  
}
```

and

```
void translateToCenter() {  
  x_variable = width/2;  
  y_variable = height/2;  
  z_variable = 10;       //how far back it goes is up to you  
}
```